# Let $L$ be a splitting field of a polynomial $f(x)$, show that $[L:K]\le n!$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

Let $L$ be a splitting field of a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ with coefficients in
a field $K$, show  that $[L:K]\le n!$.

---

Since $f$ is of degree $n$, and $L$ is the splitting field, then $f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)$. Then $L=K(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$.
Now the Galois group of $K(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ is **at the most**  isomorphic to a symmetric group $S_n$ because they cannot be more than $n!$ automorphism of $K(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, thus $|G(L/K)|\le n!$

now because $L$ is a splitting field, $[L:K]=|G(L/K)|\le n!$

Is the solution correct ?

Comment: Why should the Galois group of $K(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be isomorphic to $S_k$. That is incorrect. For example the Galois group of a cyclotomic polynomial is cyclic, and all $S_k$, $k\geq3$ are not cyclic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting field $L$ of polynomial $f \in K[x]$ with degree $n$ satisfies $[L:K] | n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3688592/splitting-field-l-of-polynomial-f-in-kx-with-degree-n-satisfies-lk)

Comment: @Kolja is $f$ allowed to be cyclotomic ?

Comment: @Kolja $a_i$ must be all different because it's a splitting field and  $f$ is separable

Comment: @Kolja I edit my solution  a bit. Maybe now it's ok

Comment: What does it mean to be "at the most isomorphic''? That doesn't make sense. However, you are on the right track, you just need to be a little bit more formal.